# python-nothing is happening when i run my function

Tags: python, function

When I run the code my while loop works perfectly then the program just ends even though I have a whole other function I want to run.
There is a while loop before this piece of code which ends in login = False and I have also tried replacing that with break and the same thing happens.

```
  import csv
  import sys

username="Leeman"
password="treeroad"

login = True
login_u = input("Enter username ")
login_p = input("Enter password ")

while login == True:

if login_u + login_p != username + password:
        print("incorrect login")
        sys.exit()
elif login_u != username:
        print("incorrect login")
        sys.exit()
elif login_p != password:
        print ("incorrect login")
        sys.exit()
elif login_u + login_p == username + password:
        print("Welcome to the system")
        login = False    

def main_menu():

print("---------------------------------School Menu-----------------------------------")
option=input("""Options:
                    1-Enter new student details
                    2-Search for student by ID number
                    3-View student details
                    4-Reports
                    5-Logout
                    Where do you want to go, 1,2,3,4 or 5?
                    """)

if option == "1":
   details=input("Enter your new student's details in format:ID Number,Forename,Surname,Gender,Tutor Group,DOB(dd/mm/yyyy),Phone Number,School Email: ")
   appendfile=open('classinfo.csv ' , 'a')
   appendfile.write(details)
   appendfile.close
   main_menu()

elif option=='2':
    with open ('classinfo.csv' , 'r') as classinfoFile:
        idnumber = input("Input the ID number of the student you wish to view")
        classinfoReader = csv.reader(classinfoFile)
        for row in classinfoReader:
            for field in row:
                if field == idnumber:
                   print (row)
                   main_menu()
```

The aim of this code is you select what you want to do with the csv file by selecting a number(1-5) then after you have done it to go back to the school menu. However the entire function is just not running at all.Why??

Comment: Rearrange your code please

Comment: rearrange it in what way ,would you like?

Comment: Your indentation looks confusing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at our ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. As that page says, we’d love to help you, but we can't do that without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: also, at some point you have to actually call your function for it to run.

Comment: @patrick That's why I said his indentation looks confusing, he called the function at the last line, I don't know if this is a call or recursion

Comment: (1) Splitting the code for each option off into its own function will help you stay organized, (2) put the code in `main_menu()` in a `while True:` loop and `break` after a 5 is entered.

Comment: I think this is my problem, how do I call it to run, when I have it at the end of the if statements im trying to go back to the access menu after the if statement is done

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_one():
    print("You entered 1!")

def do_two():
    print("You entered 2!")

def main():
    while True:
        choice = int(input("Enter 1, 2, or 3 (to exit): "))
        if choice == 1:
            do_one()
        elif choice == 2:
            do_two()
        elif choice == 3:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break

main()
```

Comment: I have put that in the program to see what happens and when I run it the same thing happens, its like as soon as I type in 'def' anything after it just doesn't run at all

Comment: Um... this is an example of how you should structure your program. `def` creates a new function but doesn't run it. The code is run by the last line, where it calls `main()`. Inside `main()` you have a `while` loop which will repeat forever (or at least until you get to `break`).